# Indexing into arbitrary array in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I came across following Cypher example:

```
RETURN range(0,10)[3]
```

which outputs `3`.

I was wondering if I can index into arbitrary array something as follows:

```
MATCH a = [0,2,1,8,9] AS collection
RETURN a[2]
```

I was expecting it to print `1` since its the number at the index 2 in the collection. But it gives error:

```
Invalid input '[': expected whitespace, comment
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in you style:

MATCH () WITH [0, 2, 1, 8, 9] AS a LIMIT 1 RETURN a[2]

It is doing the following thing:
Match finds the first node but it pushes your constant array into the pipeline (only once because of LIMIT 1) and RETURN gives back the third element.